# doubt about contradiction

Tags: bhagavad-gita, philosophy, vedanta, upanishads, shloka

In Upanishad it says "Uttisthata Jagrata Prapya Varannibodhata"/ "Arise, awake, and stop not till the goal is reached" and in Gita, it says "Karmanye Vadhikaraste Ma Phaleshou Kada Chana
Ma Karma Phala Hetur Bhurmatey Sangostva Akarmani".

My question is there any contradiction that in Upanishad it says focus/think about the result/goal whereas Gita says don't focus/think about the result/goal?

Comment: The Upanishad is talking about the spiritual goal of experiencing Brahman. Gita is talking about not worrying about the result of action in this world. They are talking about two different things.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay Isn't Arise awake ........ also about daily/carrier goals ?

Comment: @quantity No, the Upanishad is not talking about any worldly goal or result but about experiencing Brahman.

Comment: Gita also says Arise!(engage in action) - 4.42 (aathishto uthishta Bharatha). Here, Gita seems to emphasize only on the attitude with which the action is done. If goal of action is not  ,personal benefit , self reward or appreciation , rather for the greater good.(3.16 evaṁ pravartitaṁ chakraṁ),  one can become the instrument of God. thereby is in the pathway of attaining the highest purushartha, the spiritual goal said in upanishad  . so there is no contradiction.

Comment: You creatures, who are sleeping in ignorance that 
has no beginning, *uttisthata*, arise, turn towards the 
knowledge of the Self; *jagrata*, awake -put an end 
to the sleep of ignorance which is terrible by nature, 
and is the seed of all evil. How (to put an end to it)? 
*Prapya*, approaching; *vardn*, the adorable ones, the 
excellent teachers-who know that (Self); *nibodhata*, 
learn--understand the all-pervading Self, taught 
by them, as 'I am that'.(Sripad HH Adi Shankaracharya Bhasyam on Katha Upanishad Part I Canto III Verse 14 translated by Swami Gambhirananda)

Comment: Here, the concern of the question seems to be an issue of consistency in comparison with Gita.
Sri Shankara Bhasya (whose target audience -(adhikari) - is mumukshu).(quoted by @Rāmachandra ji ) alone suffices , exclusively for the stated Upanishadic verse .But in perspective of Gita(5.4 ubhayor vindate phalam), yoga and sankya(knowledge) do not target at different results,but are stages in progress towards the same goal  ,Hence no contradiction. Gita exalts/eulogizes saadhana(means) , more than the saadhya(goal), as means is important to attain the goal.

Comment: A transport is imperative for a traveller until the destination is reached , although it is abandoned after that.

Comment: Also the word *goal* occuring in two different contexts in the last paragraph of the question , has different connotations.

Comment: It would be more useful to give the chapter and verse when giving a quote from a source. The comparison is in appropriate, there is no contradiction. Also note that asking if there is a contradiction is  like asking for opinions which is off topic.

Comment: Could someone write an answer...